# react semantic ui Header menu

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using `semantic-ui-react` for creating a Header. 
I use `Menu` item for that and here is my code :

```
 export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu stackable>
        <Menu.Item name="search">
          <Search />
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item name="username">
          <User username="user" />
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item name="bell">
          <Bell />
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Menu position="right">
          <Menu.Item name="search">
            <img src={logo} />
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu.Menu>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

and in App container:

```
return (
    <Container fluid > 
       <Header />
    </Container>
```

but the what i see and render on page is like a list and and haven't any style and even not looklike on doc page example: [Doc's](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu#menu-example-menus#menu)
is there any thing i missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Installing Semantic UI React provides the JavaScript for your
>   components. You'll also need to include a stylesheet to provide the
>   styling for your components

You can do:

```
$ npm install semantic-ui-css --save
```

After install, include in your JS file:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```